# Dimension of Vector Space From Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the rank-nullity theorem to show that if $V =\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}: x+y+z = 0, x+2y+3z =0$ that $\dim($V$) = 2.$

I verified that the dimension is 2 by finding a basis from the RREF of the system of constraints, but I'm not sure what role the rank-nullity theorem plays here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Your space is the Nullspace of 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 &1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 &3 &0 \end{bmatrix}$$
[the zeros correspond to the fourth variable which is missing from the equation].

Now the two rows of you matrix are not proportional, hence linearly independent. Thus $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$.

What does the rank-nullity theorem say?

Comment: So null($A$) = 0 and rank($A$) = 2? I don't see why null($A$) has to be zero though.

Comment: @MathLogic The rank-nullity theorem says that the rank plus the nullity is the number of COLUMNS of A ;)

Comment: So null($V$) = 2. But I still don't see how that shows that dim($V$) = 2?

Comment: $W$ is the Null space of the matrix ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you expound upon your explanations a bit more? I can't figure out what you are trying to get at.

Comment: @MathLogic What is the definition of the Null space of $A$?